# Constant column in child partition tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

We are using inheritance based partitioning in our application. The partitioning is on a column such that each partition has a different value for this column. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE base(
    tblock INT NOT NULL,
    -- other fields --
);

-- Create a partition
CREATE TABLE partition_1(
    CHECK(tblock=1),
    INHERITS base
);
```

There are a lot of such partitions, and each one has a large number of records (in the millions). Overall database size is in the terabytes.

In the above schema, the partitions have to have a column tblock, even though each partition has a constant value for that column in all rows. This is clearly a waste of space on disk.

Is there any way to declare the partitions so that it does not actually store the value of tblock on disk?

We are currently on Postgresql 9.2.6.

Comment: Not unless there's some *other* key that also exclusively identifies what goes in which partition. How do you know which row gets which tblock?

Comment: @CraigRinger tblock determines which partition each row goes into and is used in the WHERE clause for constraint exclusion. It means time block. There is no other key. The data structure is somewhat more complicated than shown of course.

Comment: OK, so the application has some way to know what the "tblock" for a row of interest is? If so, consider having the application just query the partitions directly rather than relying on constraint exclusion; that way you no longer need the `tblock` fields.

Comment: @CraigRinger thanks. It would be possible but quite painful. Queries often span a lot of partitions. We do use that for some query types though.

Comment: I don't see any easy solution then. Pg's partitioning is pretty primitive. Hey, we're looking for interested people to contribute to a better partitioning solution .... keen to get into the guts of the source code? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

of course you can write trigger which will skip some columns, but if you do that, you will lose benefits from partitioning [(constraint exclusions)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-CONSTRAINT-EXCLUSION)

you cant drop this column if table is inherited

here's some example

```
create table base(i integer, j integer);
CREATE TABLE
create table inh_1() inherits (base);
CREATE TABLE
create table inh_2() inherits (base);
CREATE TABLE

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION part_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
if NEW.j = 1 THEN INSERT INTO inh_1 (i) VALUES (NEW.i);
    ELSIF NEW.j = 2 THEN INSERT INTO inh_2 (i) VALUES (NEW.i);
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION

CREATE TRIGGER insert_base
    BEFORE INSERT ON base
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE part_trigger();
CREATE TRIGGER


insert into base values (100,1);
INSERT 0 0
insert into base values (140,2);
INSERT 0 0
sebpa=# select * from base;
  i  | j
-----+---
 100 |
 140 |
(2 rows)

sebpa=# select * from inh_1;
  i  | j
-----+---
 100 |
(1 row)

sebpa=# select * from inh_2;
  i  | j
-----+---
 140 |
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but we need the constraint exclusion.

Comment: there's no other way :( remember that if you want to use constraint exclusion you have to use 'CHECK' on 'partition' column